# Declare field with NaN value

Tags: typescript, nan

I want to write

```
var a: number[] & { "-1"?: NaN } = []
```

But get an error

> 'NaN' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.

Of course I can write

```
var a: number[] & { "-1"?: number /* NaN */ } = []
```

But I wanted to be more expressive and specify NaN like it works with any other value:

```
var a: number[] & { "-1"?: -42 } = []
```

**How can I make it with NaN?**

Comment: Yeah, I think you'd be much better served with a null there instead.

Comment: You can't, [they said no](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15135) (not that I really buy the "`NaN` isn't really a unit type" argument in there.  Oh well!

Comment: @AlexWayne, no, `undefined-1` is `NaN`, not `null`.